# Export variables into two columns

Tags: powershell

`"$psIP 
     $psName 
     $psPower  $psVar1 
     $psWattage $psVar2 
     $psRED $psVar3 
     $psHE $psVar4 
     $psL1 $psVar5 
     $psP1 $psVar6 
     $psStat1 $psVar7 
     $psL2 $psVar8 
     $psP2 $psVar9 
      $psStat2 $psVar10"| Out-File -FilePath P:\root\ResultFolder\Fingers1.csv`

Sorry I am very new to powershell but I do have some background in coding.

I have set two sets of variables all in the same script. The goal is to have them in two columns so that way when the script executes it can be easily filtered. I need to know how to specify which VAR goes to which column. Please ask any question.

Comment: Paste the code here, don't use screenshots. Also, you can use Export-CSV instead of Out-file.

Comment: "$psIP 
$psName 
$psPower "" $psVar1 
$psWattage $psVar2 
$psRED $psVar3 
$psHE $psVar4 
$psL1 $psVar5 
$psP1 $psVar6 
$psStat1 $psVar7 
$psL2 $psVar8 
$psP2 $psVar9 
$psStat2 $psVar10" | Out-File -FilePath P:\root\ResultFolder\Fingers1.csv -Append

Comment: I know but does Export-csv have any parameters that would change the results?

Comment: @Angela Please [update your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58629369/edit) - as you can see, comments are not that nice for code formatting :)

Comment: Would a psobject fix this? Or add to the solution?

Comment: @Angela - perhaps you could step back a bit ... how are you getting all these individual $Vars? normally one would put them into a collection of  some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to create a csv file with specific values in each row/column - see if this is what you're looking for:

```
@"
$psIP,$psName 
$psPower,$psVar1 
$psWattage,$psVar2 
$psRED,$psVar3 
$psHE,$psVar4 
$psL1,$psVar5 
$psP1,$psVar6 
$psStat1,$psVar7 
$psL2,$psVar8 
$psP2,$psVar9 
$psStat2,$psVar10
"@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine | Out-File -FilePath P:\root\ResultFolder\Fingers1.csv -Encoding ascii
```

The solution uses a Here String piped to split operator to break up the rows.
Also notice i'm using `-Encoding ascii` - this is so that Excel will see the file correctly when you open it.